# CEGUI - Loading Resources from DLL

Tags: c++, cegui

I'm using CEGUI 0.8.2. How can I load all resources from binary? I've created resource only dll containing all needed resources such as *.ttf .font .schema .imageset .looknfeel* and *.png* for imageset. I'm using Direct3D renderer and no graphics engine. I know how to load resources from files stored on hard drive, but I want to encapsulate some of these resources into a dll file. There are some methods in current api to load it from `RawDataContainer`.

e.g.

```
FontManager::getSingleton().createFromContainer(rawFont);
```

but this loads .font xml that referencing font.ttf, so how to load ALL resources from binary file? even .ttf and .png files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got an information from official cegui forum that only way how to do it, is to create custom  resource provider by extending `ResourceProvider` class and implement `loadRawDataContainer` function. Then you have to initialize cegui system manually instead of calling `bootstrapSystem` function.

Manual initialization:

```
guiRenderer = &Direct3D11Renderer::create(device, context); 
if (System::getSingletonPtr()) CEGUI_THROW(InvalidRequestException("CEGUI::System object is already initialised.")); 
System::create(*guiRenderer, &ceguiResourceProvider); // inject custom resource provider
```